Wiring hot leads from two pickups to single pot
I am wishing to wire up my telecaster so that the tone control acts as a "blend" or "fade" knob (whatever you want to call it).
I have done a lot of reading and not only were the early telecasters like this, but many people wire the second tone on a Strat to do the same thing: if in bridge position, bridge pickup on full and tone blends/fades the signal from the neck pickup. Opposite for being in the third position where you have the neck on full and bridge is the one that's being blended in.
My question is, I have two ways I've seen this wired:

the hot lead from each pickup being extended from where it meets the switch, one attached to one outside lug of the pot, and one to the middle lug.
have the hot from where the neck pickup is connected to the switch extended to one of the outside lugs of the pot, and extending the signal from the switch to the volume, then to the inside lug of the blend pot.

My experience is limited as is my understanding of how all this works. I'll upload a simple diagram of both options. I would love if someone could explain if either will work, and how it would work.
Again my apologies if I'm asking too much.



The question would be easier to understand if you attached the diagram showing how the switch works. Is it a 3 way switch?

Yes, my apologies, it's a 3-Way.
What would be the best way to present how the switch is working? To be honest, with both wirings, I don't really understand how they function. I.E. I don't see how then signal flow is allowing the fade/blend.

I'm still not catching on.
Do you wish for the modified Tone Pot to act as a gradual "fade" from one pickup to both and then the other?
Like the three way switch acts, but in a progressive fashion, rather than the hard, "this, both, and then that" options?

@stefmikhail for example this image: https://www.fralinpickups.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Telecaster-Wiring.png shows which terminals are connected in each switch position, but I'm not sure how it relates to your diagram. Is the switch in your diagram by chance a mirror image of the one I linked? Which terminals are A0, A1 etc.?

This is not my area but from looking st the diagrams, worst case, if you don’t get a definitive answer the two diagrams are similar enough that you only have to change a few wires to try both.

@Sparquelito I wish when in switch position 1 (bridge), the bridge pickup signal full, and what would be the tone pot instead blending/fading in the signal from the neck pickup, in parallel. When in position 3 (neck) I wish the opposite to happen. I believe one of those diagrams allow that but the other only for the bridge.

@user1079505 Yes I too was confused by the position of the lugs, but I have seen them displayed either way and the functionality is essentially the same. The offset is just the opposite, i.e. the A terminals are shifted up but are still the same. This video doesn't wire it the same, but explains the layout: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avxbn_ElHMI

@JohnBelzaguy That was my thought as well. Kind of the same for treble bleed and tone caps: you can always swap them out once you get started. I thought this would be an interesting mod allowing for many different tones.

Not an answer, but while you're at it, consider changing to a 4-way switch. That involves a bit of extra wire fiddling, but will reward you with an extra tone. Did it on my Tele years ago!

I followed the switch schematic from the video you linked:

Position 1  Position 2  Position 3
 ,-A1          A1          A1
 |   B1-.        B1-.        B1-.
 | A2   |    ,-A2   |      A2   |
 |   B2-'    |   B2 |        B2 |
 | A3        | A3   |    ,-A3   |
 |   B3      |   B3-'    |   B3 |
 `-A4        `-A4        `-A4   |
     B4          B4          B4-'


Hot wire of neck pickup connected to B1, Bridge pickup to A4
Position 1 connects A4-A1, and B2-B1
Position 2 connects A4-A2, and B3-B1
Position 3 connects A4-A3, and B4-B1

I was able to trace the signal flow in all three positions, for both diagrams in your post, i.e.
I believe the Method 1 is what you want:

Position 1 gives bridge pickup, with the tone pot allowing to add the neck pickup (in parallel).
Position 2 gives two pickups in parallel. The tone pot does nothing.
Position 3 gives neck pickup, with the tone pot allowing to add the bridge pickup in parallel.

Both in positions 1 and 3, the tone pot controls the amount of blend the same way, so in one extreme setting all 3 positions would sound the same, and in the other extreme setting there would be (almost) no blending.
Note, the tone pot in the diagram is logarithmic. Again, I can't remember which way the log pot turns, but depending on which pair of terminals on the pot you use (you need to use the middle, and one of the side ones), the blending will be more or less smooth.
Method 2 is similar, with one exception:

Position 3 gives only neck pickup. The tone pot does nothing.

You could add blending, by connecting the A3 terminal to the third (unconnected) terminal of the tone pot. This would make blending work in the opposite way for positions 1 and 3, i.e. pot setting for maximum blending in position 1 would correspond to no blending in position 3, and the other way round. You probably would prefer a linear pot rather than logarithmic.
Edit: Below I'm attaching diagrams of the electrical circuits, for both methods in all 3 position of the switches. Please note in Method 1 Position 3 and Method 2 Position 1 some of the paths cross without connection. In Method 2 Position 3 I also added in yellow possible extra connection that would allow blending.


Brilliant response! Thank you very much.
First off, I 100% am just starting to learn this stuff, and I know my understanding of the circuit and how it all operates together is incomplete. I really need to learn how to read and write this sort of thing as a true circuit diagram. So if you have the time to sketch these out, I wouldn't complain, but also I don't want to put you out in any way.

Indeed Method 1 sounds like the better of the two.
When it comes to lugs, do I have to be worried about having reverse function in the blend/fade for Position 1. & Position 3?
I have been wondering if I should go log or linear... linear makes more sense to me (and this will actually be a push-pull where down the pot acts as a normal tone, and I've wondered how tone would be linear...). My main reason for thinking of using log is that it's the closest to no-load, if that makes sense? Although with push-pull I could still have complete isolation in the down position. Opinion?

@stefmikhail no, the function of the pot will not be reverse. So this is different from systems where a pot replaces the switch entirely, i.e. extreme pot positions give only one pickup, and the middle position gives the blend of the two. That's not wrong at all though, just wanted to state it clearly.

@stefmikhail I would think the log pot (connected correctly) would give more gradual changing allowing for better control, while linear would work faster, more like a switch. But one would need to see it in practice, because e.g. many people prefer linear pots for volume. I'm not sure what do you mean by no-load. Given the pickup impedance is around 10kOhm, with 250kOhm pot, in the minimum pot position, the attenuation would be around 28 dB, and this doesn't depend if it's log or linear.

I was thinking that with a no-load pot, when turned all the way off, the blend would be bypassed, not allowing any of the other pickup's signal. Maybe I'm thinking of this in the wrong way. Like I said, I don't think that would matter in my case as I can just bypass this circuit for the typical one with the push-pull. But overall with the diagram I provided, I could see it beneficial to have no-load to isolate a pickup completely. Again, if I'm making any sense. lol.

@stefmikhail ah, I get it. Yes, no-load pot would be probably easier to use than push-pull.

@stefmikhail see the updated answer with the diagrams
